# What is the behavior where one closes their nose with their lips to elude foul odour called?

Tags: word-choice, expressions, expression-choice

I have seen [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/66654/23918), and it is not exactly what I'm asking. Sometimes people (most especially in developing countries) raise the tip of their lips to cover their nose when a foul odour is sensed or to jeer a person. In my own language this is called '*isu imi*' (To jam the nose), I'm writing a short story and I'm trying to find the best way to describe the phenomena.

Comment: Sounds like you would need prehensile lips for that

Comment: Strangle related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/66654/2085

Comment: gross, obviously!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's called "curling one's lip". That phrase does *not* usually imply actually blocking one's nostrils, but sometimes it does:

> Their sickly sweet scent cloyed the damp air around him, and he **curled his lip** to drive the smell out of his nostrils. [[link](http://books.google.com/books?id=lE5oliwmM6YC&pg=PA9&dq=%22curled+his+lip%22)]
>
> He **curled his lip** against the smell as he sloshed through the puddled urine across the pissoir's shaft base; […] [[link](http://books.google.com/books?id=MoggSZ9X4csC&pg=PT568&dq=%22curled+his+lip%22)]

Even — especially — when it doesn't involve actually blocking your nostrils, it's still an expression of anger, scorn, disgust, or similar.

Answer (score 9):

Swimmers call this [*the human nose clip*.](http://blog.swimator.com/2011/07/human-nose-clip-getting-water-up-my.html)

[image]

[image]

If you can contort your face enough to do that, you won't have to wear one of these to keep water out of your nose:

[image]

Comment: Nice pictures. +1

Comment: i thought lip-curling was more of an Elvis-mouth type thing...

Answer (score 4):

Most people simply [wrinkle their nose](http://www.mostphotos.com/1626000/wrinkled-nose) when they smell something foul.

An [expression of disgust](http://www.123rf.com/photo_12379299_young-man-expressing-disgust.html) may involve everting the lips as you describe, but a person with such an expression is still wrinkling their nose.